# How can I deploy content below a row in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Can somebody help me to do the following in Swift:

I have two elements called Topic 1 and Topic 2.
[image]

I need to click on the Topic 1 (in the down arrow image), then deploy some content just under my Topic 1 section.

I use a UITableView to display the data (topic 1 & topic 2 rows), but I don't know if displaying content below each row like the following image is possible with an UITableView.

[image]

Anyone know a way to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two high level options:

1. Display topics as section headers instead of rows. Detect tap of
   section header and track the "active" section in your table view
   data source. Only return a row count greater than 0 for the "active"
   section. When the "active" section changes, reload the old section
   and the new section.
2. Create a cell that displays both the "Topic" and any details. Implement the table view's delegate and return a height that shows the details only for the "active" topic. For all other rows, return a height that will only show the header. When the selection changes, reload the old and new rows to animate the height changes.

Comment: Hi drewag : ) thank you so much, I only have one concern : which function can I use to detect the header click? I only know the one for the cell (didSelectTableViewCellAtIndex....).

Comment: @JuanVillalvazo you can use a tap gesture recognizer or a button in the header view

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to "deploy the content" *below* the cell. Add it *to* the cell. In other words, you modify the cell or replace it with another cell built exactly to accommodate this extra material.

Comment: I see, I like this solution but... how can I format the text in a way that Topic 1 seems like the title and below the title seems like the content? Because I only know how to show cells with one line.

Comment: You can design a cell in any way you like. You can even lay it out in real time if different cells have different numbers of rows.